# Android geofence BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, google-api-client, geofencing, android-geofence

I have implemented geofences using the GoogleApiClient -> when triggered, a Service connects to the GoogleApiClient and adds several Geofences.

Before I had another IntentService registered as "callback" for geofence events. This worked more or less, but only when the app was in foreground. As I want to get geofence events also when the app is in background/closed, I searched a little and moved the callback from an IntentService to a BroadcastReceiver, now I don't even get geofence events when the app is in foreground.

I have already asked the internet for solutions (most common answer: change event listener from Service to BroadCastReceiver - but this made things worse)

Here is my setup:

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".service.GeofenceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".service.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".service.GeofenceRegistrationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      GeofenceRegistrationService.startService(context,true);
  }
}
```

GeofenceReceiver:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Logger.e(this, "GeofenceReceiver called");

      GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

      if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
          Logger.e(this, String.valueOf(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode()));

      } else {
        Logger.i(this, geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation().getLatitude() + ", " +geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation().getLongitude());

      }
  }
}
```

GeofenceRegistrationService:

```
public class GeofenceRegistrationService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {


  public static final String KEY_FORCE_CLEAN = "FORCE_CLEAN";

  public static void startService(Context context, boolean forceClean) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceRegistrationService.class);

      intent.putExtra(KEY_FORCE_CLEAN, forceClean);

      context.startService(intent);

  }

  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (isLocationPermissionGranted() && intent != null) {

        startGeofenceRegistration();

    } else {

        this.stopSelf(startId);

    }

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
  }

  public void startGeofenceRegistration() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = buildAPIClient();
    }

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        registerGeofences();
    }
  }


  private boolean isLocationPermissionGranted() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
  }

  private synchronized GoogleApiClient buildAPIClient() {

    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

  }

  private void addGeoFences() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    createGeofencesRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Logger.e(this, securityException);
        }
    }
  }

  private void removeGeoFences() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            Logger.e(this, securityException);
        }
    }
 }

 private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceEventHandlingService.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE");
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult  connectionResult) {
    Logger.d(this, "CONNECTION_FAILED");
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Logger.d(this, "CONNECTED");
    registerGeofences();

  }

  private void registerGeofences() {
    removeGeoFences();
    addGeoFences();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Logger.d(this, "connection suspended");
  }

  private GeofencingRequest createGeofencesRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

    List<Poi> pois = Config.getPersistenceService().getPois();

    int counter = 0;
    for (Poi p : pois) {
        if (p.isCoordinateSet()) {
            Geofence fence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(String.valueOf(p.getId()))
                    .setCircularRegion(p.getLat(), p.getLon(), 2500) // TODO
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                    .build();

            builder.addGeofence(fence);

            counter++;
        }
    }

    Logger.i(this, "added geofences: " + counter);

    return builder.build();
  }


  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Logger.d(this, "Geofences added");

    } else {
        Logger.d(this, "Failed to add geofences");
    }
  }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I oversee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've gotten to work but keep in mind I'm adding and removing my Geofences from an Activity and receiving the Geofence Transitions in an IntentService.

I think you should try building your `Intent` specifying `new Intent(context, YourReceiverClass)` and  create your `PendingIntent` using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. Here's what I used though:

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent(){
    // Re-use the Pending Intent if it already exists
    if(mGeofencePendingIntent != null){
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    // The intent for the IntentService to receive the transitions
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);

    // Create the pending intent
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

And inside my IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

       // Do something with geofences

    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks Sammy. While changing all possible parts, I have overseen the PendingIntent.getService(), which indeed needs to be PendingIntent.getBroadcast().

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was facing a similar problem, but in my case I wanted to do the opposite, change from Service to a Broadcast. And after checking your question I noticed that maybe you were not receiving the geofence transition on you Broadcast because you were requesting a Service in your getPendingIntent method.

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    (...)
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    (...)
  }
```

In my case I put getBroadcast instead and worked fine.

```
mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope it helped you.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

in your posted code, your intent filter was wrong.

Instead of :

```
    <receiver
    android:name=".service.GeofenceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

you should have used :

```
    <receiver
    android:name=".service.GeofenceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```