# Interface Object has null value in Broadcast onReceive method

Tags: android, interface, broadcastreceiver

I made an interface to get a trigger from a broadcast receiver, but it always says interface object has null value!

This is the code of the Broadcast Receiver class in which the interface is defined:

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public interface ResultListener {
    public void SomeWorkToDo();
}

private ResultListener resultListener;

public void setter(ResultListener listener){
    Log.i("setter","working");
     this.resultListener=listener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
        Log.i("Geo Fencing broadcast","Running");
        Toast.makeText(context, "You Are Arrived!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resultListener.SomeWorkToDo();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the code of the Manifest file:

`<receiver android:name=".GeoFencing.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver" />`

This code is used in the MainActivity:

```
GeofenceBroadcastReceiver geofenceBroadcastReceiver=new GeofenceBroadcastReceiver();
    geofenceBroadcastReceiver.setter(new GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void SomeWorkToDo() {
            Log.i("our interface","working");
            startActivity(new Intent(ViewPlace.this,ViewDirections.class));
            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: "`setter()`" is a *TERRIBLE* name.  Please use the correct Java naming convention: `setResultListener()`.  This is especially important for frameworks that use reflection.  ALSO: Does this answer your question? [Android geofence BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414838/android-geofence-broadcastreceiver)

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the receiver in the manifest. Your `new GeofenceBroadcastReceiver()` is not going to be used. Android will create its own instance of `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver` when a broadcast for that receiver is received. As a result, the callback will be `null`, because your setter is not called.

It it very likely that using a system broadcast is the wrong solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve. If you are convinced that a system broadcast is the right answer, and you wish to keep the receiver registered in the manifest, `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver` needs to be able to do all of its work on its own, without any sort of callbacks from other objects.

Comment: If i use constructor instead of setter then it will be okay?

Comment: @ALIRAZA: No, because you are not creating the instance of `GeofenceBroadcastReceiver` that is receiving the `Intent`. The framework is.

Comment: Actually i want to call dialogfragment.show(fragmentmanager,"string") method in onReceive() method,but i cant due to fragment manager ,,,

Comment: @ALIRAZA: "Actually i want to call dialogfragment.show(fragmentmanager,"string") method in onReceive() method" -- you may not have a UI at the time of receiving the broadcast. You are registering for this broadcast in the manifest. Therefore, you are saying that at any time, you are expecting to receive a broadcast, but you may not have a process when that happens. Android will fork a process for you and hand you the broadcast `Intent`, but you will not have an activity at that time.

Comment: @ALIRAZA: At this point, I am even more convinced that what I wrote in the answer is true: "It it very likely that using a system broadcast is the wrong solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve". Certainly using a manifest-registered receiver is the wrong solution, if your objective is to display a UI upon receipt of the broadcast.

Comment: @CommmonsWare: Are you trying to saying registering receiver in manifest file is wrong or totally broadcast receiver method is wrong?

Comment: @ALIRAZA: If your `GeofencingEvent` is [this Google stuff](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing), then you appear to need to provide a `PendingIntent`. If you want those events to be delivered to your activity, the simplest solution is to call `createPendingResult()` on your activity. That will return a `PendingIntent` that, when triggered, calls your `onActivityResult()` method in the same activity. You can then eliminate the receivers, and your `GeofencingEvent` will be in your activity where you can use it to update the UI.

Comment: :hey!!!i tried your method but onActivtyResult() method didnt get called..

Comment: @ALIRAZA: You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing how you are setting up the geofence and how you are determining if `onActivityResult()` is being called.